# Checking for instanceOf but not executing

Tags: java

```
  private void createObject(List<Activities> listOfActivities){
    ABC object1 = new ABC();
    String value = "";
    if (listOfActivities instanceof XYZ) {
        for (Activities list: listOfActivities) {
            value= ((XYZ) list).getValue();
        }
        object1.setValue(value)
        listOfActivities.add(object1);
      }
  }
```

In this method, listOfActivities has some values of Type XYZ. So 'if' block should execute which is checking if listOfActivities is an instance of class XYZ, but its not executing.
Why?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your variable `listOfActivities` is of type `List` and thus can never be of type `XYZ`. You have to check each object in this list.

Comment: But I have used generics here. So I think, its a List of Activities type.

Comment: Exactly. It's a List<Activities> type. It can never be XYZ.  The XYZ type isn't related at all with the List<Activities> type

Comment: If you have a _drawer_ full of _socks_, do you then call the drawer a sock?

Comment: No ,drawer only. Now I got it. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

A `List<String>` is of type `List`, not `String`.

So your `List<Activity>` is of type `List` and will return `false` for `instanceof Activity`.

The objects you retrieve *from* the list will be of type `Activity`.

For this scenario:

```
List< Activity > list = new ArrayList<>() ;
list.add( new Activity() ) ;
```

…let’s try:

```
boolean isListAnActivity = list instanceof Activity ;  // false
boolean isElementOfListAnActivity = list.get( 0 ) instanceof Activity ;  // true
```

See this [code run live at IdeOne.com](https://ideone.com/vP181a).

> isListAnActivity: false
>
> isElementOfListAnActivity: true

Comment: Oh okay. I got it.